# Fixed points and stability of them

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Find the fixed points and classify them for the system of equations:

$$x'=v$$
$$v'=-x+wx^3$$
$$w'=-w$$

$$0=v$$
$$0=-x+wx^3$$
$$1=wx^2$$
$$0=w$$

is the only fixed point (0,0,0)??

jacobian:
\begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox0 & 1 & 0 \\
\mbox-1+3wx^2 & 0 & x^3 \\
\mbox0 & 0 & -1 \\
 \end{array}

evaluated at the fixed point:

\begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox0 & 1 & 0 \\
\mbox-1 & 0 & 0 \\
\mbox0 & 0 & -1 \\
 \end{array}

eigenvalues: -1, i, -i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(0,0,0) is indeed your only fixed point,  but when you evaluated $-1 +3wx^2$, you got 0 instead of -1 like you should have.  Switching to -1 in row 2, column 1,  you get eigenvalues of $-1,\pm i$.  Hence you have a nonhyperbolic fixed point, you have stability but not asymptoptically stable if I recall correctly for this case.

Comment: :Could you tell me how to compute the fixed point of $\cos x$.Because I couldn't really get the term 'fixed-point algorithm'.

Comment: @justin Sure that your comment applies to *this* answer (even to this page)?

Comment: @justin Umm...cos x?  Without more context, that seems very out of place

Comment: @Alan:The reason why I would like to ask this question is because we have to stdy fixed point algorithm in compiler design.So I think to study this algorith first we have to know what 'fixed point' means.But I looked in wikipedia and got the meaning but while looking in http://1drv.ms/1ETRRk1 it says that $cos(x)$ has an fixed point.But I couldn't get which point it might be?Could you help me.

Comment: @justin That is a completely different definition of fixed point, with a completely different meaning.  This question isn't the appropriate place to ask that,  I suggest opening a new question about $cos x=x$